# capybara ruby code to check an element is present or not

Tags: xpath, capybara

using capybara how can i check an element is present or not.

i used following code but it is not working

```
page.should_not have_selector('#confirmation_code')
<div style="width:250px;display:block;float:right;text-align:right;">
                <span id="email_text">Order Number:<br></span>
                <input id="confirmation_code" type="text">
            </div>
```

i want to check above text box element is present or not?

Comment: Do you want this check as an assertion (ie to mark a test as pass/fail) or for conditional logic (ie if element present do something else do something else)?

Comment: yes i want to check if that text is present then my test will pass.if text not present the test will faul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So going from the last comment from Sush,

The first line in the code in the question is not correct at all. That will verify that the element is not shown.

You could use the following instead:

```
page.should have_css('#confirmation-code')
```

or if you wanted the text within do this:

```
page.find('#confirmation-code[type="text"]')
```

I will be honest though I am going by what I think the question is, it is not very clear what you are looking to achieve.